# Вращающийся элемент SVG выглядит слегка подпрыгивающим

Tags: css, html5, css3, svg, css-animation

Я искал в существующих вопросах ответ на мой запрос, но не нашел решения.
Я использовал анимацию `css3`. Ниже пример на `fiddle`.
https://jsfiddle.net/gamerVinod/d21c6bcb/5/

```
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
       transform: rotate(0deg);
       transform-origin: center;
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform-origin: center;
    }
}

.rotate-element {
    animation: rotate 1s infinite linear;
}
```

Всякий раз, когда я использую SVG и вращаю его, он слегка подпрыгивает.
Я не в состоянии выяснить, является ли это из-за SVG пути `<path>` или есть другая причина. Может кто-то, пожалуйста, поможет мне узнать причину этого и как это исправить?

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094766/rotating-svg-element-looks-like-bouncing-slightly/41096118#41096118

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как @Ouroborus сказал, кривые Безье могут быть лишь приблизительными дугами. Если вам нужно вращать эти формы, тогда, если ваша фигура будет аккуратно и качественно обработана, вы, вероятно, увидите некоторые вибрации.

Можно использовать дуги `(A)` элемента пути. Но вам этого не нужно делать. Однозначно самым простым решением здесь, является использование фактического `<circle>` - круга.

```css
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}

.rotate-element {
    animation: rotate 1s infinite linear;
}

.parent{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  text-align: center;
}

.child{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <svg class="child rotate-element" version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="13.25" opacity="0.2" fill="none"
            stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"/> 
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="13.25" fill="none"
            stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"
            stroke-dasharray="6 80"/> 
  </svg>
</div>
```

Здесь я использую два круга с толщиной строки (линий) - `"3"` и прозрачную заливку - `fill="none"`. Нижний круг полу-прозрачный `opacity="0.2"` (как и в оригинальном SVG).

Верхний круг имеет лишь часть своей обводки, нарисованные с помощью `stroke-dasharray="6 80"`.

Источник: [Rotating svg element looks like bouncing slightly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau) @Paul LeBeau